# jquery click event on bootstrap 3 tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have this code:

```
      <ul>
        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" id="one">Tab One</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" id="two">Tab Two</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" id="three">Tab Three</a></li>
      </ul>
```

I want to capture the any tab click event and alert the id of the tab being activated by the click. How is this done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
$('a[data-toggle=tab]').click(function(){
    alert(this.id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" id="one">Tab One</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" id="two">Tab Two</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" id="three">Tab Three</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4):

I would use the bootstrap events API instead of adding additional click handlers

```
$('.yourTabsClass a').on('show.bs.tab', function(e){
    alert('ID clicked = ' + e.target.id)
});
```

Reference: [bootstrap tabs docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs)

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/uw6qcqxN9CLTjU0MlrY9?p=preview)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

```
$("a[data-toggle='tab']").click(function() {
    alert($(this).attr("id"))
});
```

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ozefLx0w/)